# Unable to visualize value from the API response

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript

I'm working on my personal Portfolio for a Web Developer course, and I can't implement correctly my Api to get the information from the database. I had no problem using a .json file but now I'm trying to get the information from my localhost server.

There is no problem on the server or in the connection, because the browser console returns the table that I need to use. The thing is that when I insert the table in the html, I get the value `[object Object]`. When I try to get just one or more values from the model, it just happens nothing.
[What I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5uEQ.png)

Model.ts:

```
export class info {
  id?: String;
  name: String;
  about: String;

  constructor(name: String,about: String){
    this.name = name;
    this.about = about;
  }

}
```

HTML file:

```
<div class="card mb-1 card-body">
    <div class="card-titles">
      <h3>Acerca de</h3>
      <div class="btn-edit">
        <a href="#" class="btn-right"><i class="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p class="card-text">{{info}}</p>
  </div>
```

Component:

```
import { InfoService } from './../../services/info.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { info } from 'src/app/model/info.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-about-me',
  templateUrl: './about-me.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./about-me.component.css']
})
export class AboutMeComponent implements OnInit {
  info: info = new info("","");

  constructor(public infoService: InfoService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.infoService.getInfo().subscribe(data => {this.info = data})
  }

}
```

InfoService:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { info } from '../model/info.model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class InfoService {

  constructor(private http : HttpClient) { }

  public getInfo(): Observable<info>{
    return this.http.get<info>('http://localhost:8080/api/info/get');
  }
}
```

Response I get from my local db:

```
XHRGEThttp://localhost:8080/api/info/get
[HTTP/1.1 200  243ms]

1

[{"id":2,"name":"Eric Diaz","position":"Full Stack Web Developer Jr.","ubication":"Viedma, Rio Negro (Argentina)","banner":"https://i.imgur.com/zKNwxBl.jpg","profilePic":"https://imgur.com/rC52iuo.jpg","about":"Desarrollador Web autodidacta, encantado por aprender nuevas tecnologías, lenguajes de programación. Gran entusiasta en base de datos."}]
```

Comment: try `this.info = JSON.stringify(data)` in your TS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your response returns an array, it should be the `info[]` type but not the `info` type.

1. Return an observable of `info[]` type in the `InfoService`.

> info.service.ts

```
public getInfo(): Observable<info[]> {
  return this.http.get<info[]>('http://localhost:8080/api/info/get');
}
```

2. To extract a single object from the array, use the indexer.

> about-me.component.ts

```js
this.infoService.getInfo().subscribe((data) => {
  this.info = data[0];
});
```

3. In the view, you should use Jsonpipe to display the object in serialized format (more meaningful info than show `[object Object]`.

> about-me.component.html

```
<p class="card-text">{{ info | json }}</p>
```

Or provide the property:

```
<p class="card-text">{{ info.name }}</p>
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wdlk6h?file=src/services/info.service.ts)